# The best way to define flavor-specific navigation for NavHost with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-productflavors, jetpack-compose-navigation, white-labelling

I have a multi-flavored, modularized app. Currently, I have 4 flavors and just one feature module, e.g. `:feature:cars`

At the moment, the `:feature:cars` module should be connected only to 3 flavors out of 4. But in the future, there will be more flavors and feature modules.

For now, I define additional `composable` inside the `NavHost` using the `addSpecificNavigation` function that is created in each flavor folder, where the `:feature:cars` module is not used, the function does nothing, and in the other 3 files the code is exactly the same.

I don't like this solution,  but I can't figure out how to do it in a more correct way. Any advices?

Current `NavHost`:

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = startDestinationRoute) {
        addSpecificNavigation(navController)

        composable(Onboarding.route) {
            OnboardingScreen(appState = appState)
        }
        ...

}
```

`FlavorA/FlavorSpecificNavigation`:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.addSpecificNavigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    //no differences yet
}
```

`FlavorB/FlavorSpecificNavigation`:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.addSpecificNavigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    composable(Destination.Cars.route) {
        CarsScreen()
    }

    composable(Destination.CreateCar.route) {
        CreateCarScreen()
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decide to do it by moving all module-specific navigation to the extension function in this module.

in the `:feature:cards`, `navigation/CardsNavigation.kt`:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.cardsScreens() {
    composable(Destination.Cars.route) {
        CarsScreen()
    }

    composable(Destination.CreateCar.route) {
        CreateCarScreen()
    }
}
```

and in the `FlavorB/FlavorSpecificNavigation`:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.addSpecificNavigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    cardsScreens()
}
```